# Symbolic Linking using dates?

Tags: symlink

Is there a way of symbolic linking files that are created after a particular date? E.G if a folder has files from January up until yesterday can I symbolically link only files from last week until today?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

`find . -mtime $(date +%s -d"Aug 10, 2013 23:59:59") -mtime $(date +%s -d"Aug 1, 2013 23:59:59") -exec ln -s {} /place/to/symlink \;`